# How to redirect invalid URL in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony-1.4

/`(directory/?param=value)` cannot change this url

```
directory/?param=value
```

to

```
directory/value
```

It's not work:

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI} ^/directory/.*

RewriteRule   ^/directory/\?param=(.*)    /directory/$1 [L]
```

My problem is how to replace **?param=** ???

Answer (score 0):

These rules should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(directory)/\?param=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^(directory)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/?param=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't match against the query string (everything after the `?`) in a `RewriteRule`, try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?directory/(.+)$ /directory/?param=$1 [L]
```

That takes: **directory/value** and rewrites it internally to serve the content at **directory/?param=value**.